# Optimization: Finding Volume of a cubic rectangle.

Tags: calculus, optimization

> Question: According to postal regulations, a carton is classified as "oversized" if the sum of its height and girth (the perimeter of its base) exceeds 118 in. Find the dimensions of a carton with square base that is not oversized and has maximum volume.

Attempt: Since the base is a square,its perimeter would be $4s$ ($s =$ one side). So $h+4s=118$.
Solving for $h$, $h= 118 - 4s$.

The volume is $V = L \times W \times h$, and length and width are the same since the base is a square. So

$$V = 2s x h.$$

Substitute for $h$, $V = 2s(118-4s)$; $v = 236s-8s^2$.

Derivative of $V = 236-16s$.

Critical point at $s = 236/16 = 14.75$, which must be a max.

So length of a side is $14.75in.$, and height would be $59in.$, but its coming up as wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $V$ is not $2sh$, it is $s^2h$.

Comment: What do you mean by a *"cubic rectangle"*? Perhaps the accepted terminology is "rectangular parallelepiped" or [Cuboid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboid)

Answer (score 1):

The volume of such a container is:

$$V= s^2h$$

Where V is volume, s is one side of the square base, and h is the height. Obviously the maximum volume  will use the maximum side lengths, so we have:

$$4s+h = 118$$ 
$$h = 118-4s$$

We want the volume equation to be in terms of just one variable, so we plug in the new value of h:

$$V= s^2(118-4s) = 118s^2 -4s^3 $$

Take the derivative:

$$V'= 236s-12s^2 $$

And optimize:

$$0= 236s -12s^2=236-12s$$ 
$$s=236/12 = 59/3 $$

Solving for h gives the ideal dimensions at: 59/3" x 59/3" x 118/3"

Comment: In my answer, I'm assuming by "cubic rectangle" you mean "square prism."